# How to refer a job/project in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have an existing job **A1a1** at:

```
D:\Jenkins-Slave\workspace\scp\A\1\a1\A1a1
```

Now I want to create a new job:

```
D:\Jenkins-Slave\workspace\scp\B\1\B1
```

and **B1** should be defined as "copy from" **A1a1**.

I have tried to refer to **A1a1** in the "Copy from" field in different ways:

```
../../A/1/a1/A1a1
..\..\A\1\a1\A1a1
D:\Jenkins-Slave\workspace\scp\A\1\a1\A1a1
```

None of them works with Error "No such job..."

**Edit: I have also used the URL in the copy from field, id does not work and returns the same error.**

What is the way to refer a job that is not a sibling of the job to be created?

Comment: Do you not have the URL for the Jenkins job?

Comment: I have also tried with URL. it doesn't work

Comment: I've never entered anything but a job's name without any path in the _Copy from_ field – **A1a1** in your case. Have you tried this already?

Comment: yes I did, but it didn't work. that works only when the existing job is the **sibling** of the new job as implied in my post.

Comment: Just so that we are on the same page; In your Jenkins instance you have one top folder called `scp`, that folder contains folder `A` and `B` which both contains a folder called `1`, `scp/A/1` contains `a1` which in turn contains `A1a1` and finally `scp/B/1` contains B1? Also, when you say "copy from", are you referring to "Copy artifacts from another project" step or is it another plugin?

Comment: your understand of the hierarchic structures is correct. I am creating a new job **B1** as a copy of **A1a1**. In Jenkins wherever you click New Item, you can create a new project or new job, and there a few options in terms of the job type, one of is "copy existing item". it is copying the configurations, not the artifacts.